# Como faço retorna a soma total das palavras repetidas, dentro de todas as div?

Tags: javascript, div, for, alert

Para ilustrar o grau de dificuldade, coloco 3 `div` e dentro delas palavras idênticas, posto de propósito para somar sua duplicação.

```
<div>        <div>        <div>
   Diego       Ademir      Diego
   Maicon      Diego       Maicon
   Adriana     Maicon      Ademir
   Magda       Adriana     Adriana
   Delvair     Magda       Ademir
   Roselene    Delvair     Delvair
   Lawiny      Ademir      Lawiny
   Nicolas     Lawiny      Roselene
   Alice       Nicolas     Nicolas
   Ademir      Alice       Alice
   Júlia       Júlia       Ademir
</div>       </div>       </div>
```

Quero percorrer as 3 `div` com  `for` e, retorna o número total de repetição do nome "Ademir" no `alert`. Veja um exemplo com `array`:

```
var y = ["Diego","Maicon","Ademir","Adriana","Ademir","Delvair","Lawiny","Roselene","Nicolas","Alice","Ademir"];

var objects= {};

for (var x in y) {

objects[y[x]] = objects[y[x]]!=undefined ? objects[y[x]]+1 : 1;
}

alert("Encontramos " + objects.Ademir + " repetição do nome 'Ademir'!");
```

Baseado no exemplo dado, desejo fazer com as `div` e somar cada palavra igual encontrada dentro das 3 `div`, e retorna o seu total.

Lembrando que, para a palavra na qual deverá ser buscada/somada é de nome "Ademir".

Comment: Voce usa angular no seu projeto ?

Comment: @phdias Não, somente Javascript puro.

Comment: Diego, as DIV's estão uma dentro da outra? Porque se for todo o conteúdo só esta na div mais de dentro na tua pergunta, ou é tipo <div>João</div><div>Maria</div> ....

Comment: Diego, posta o codigo HTML das divs que fica mais facil de apontar uma solucao assertiva

Comment: @Mathias Não, estão livres. Tipo o que você mencionou `<div>João</div><div>Maria</div>` ....

Comment: @andrepaulo Observe as 3 `div` na pergunta. Isso é tudo o que tenho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta seleccionar o texto todo e contar as incidências da palavra na `string`, veja o exemplo [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/w4mva9ba/).

Criei uma `div` para *segurar* as demais, então peguei o texto seleccionado da mesma e contei as incidências.

```js
//Pega texto
var str = document.getElementById("buscaraqui").textContent;
//conta o texto
var count = (str.match(/Ademir/g) || []).length;
document.getElementById("res").textContent = count
```

```html
   <div id='buscaraqui'>

   <div>        <div>        <div>
  Diego       Ademir      Diego
  Maicon      Diego       Maicon
  Adriana     Maicon      Ademir
  Magda       Adriana     Adriana
  Delvair     Magda       Ademir
  Roselene    Delvair     Delvair
  Lawiny      Ademir      Lawiny
  Nicolas     Lawiny      Roselene
  Alice       Nicolas     Nicolas
  Ademir      Alice       Alice
  Júlia       Júlia       Ademir
   </div>       </div>       </div>

   </div>
   <p>O resultado é: <span id='res'></span></p>
```

## Outras Referências

- [textContent - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar, essa do textContent é nova pra mim, valeu, mais um aprendizado.

Comment: Valeu pelo voto. Abraço

Comment: Você mereceu! =)